# why can not we increment an array in similiar way as pointer in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, postfix-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int *p;
    p = arr;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    printf("%d\n", *arr);
    p++;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

This code outputs:

```
1
1
2
```

but when we add 2 lines as below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int *p;
        p = arr;
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        printf("%d\n", *arr);
        p++;
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        arr++;
        printf("%d\n", *arr);
    }
```

This code outputs:

```
C:\Users\Hasnat\Desktop\test.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Hasnat\Desktop\test.c|11|error: lvalue required as increment operand
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Why can not we increment an array in same way we increment pointer containing address of that array to get next element??

Comment: Because it's an array. That's kinda the answer. It just decays into a pointer if needed, but is a completely different animal.

Comment: You're trying to increment the _address_ of arr there.

Comment: You cant treat arrays and pointers similarly .You cannot use array as lvalue .

Comment: Of course that doesn't explain why `void f(int arr[]) {arr++;}` compiles without error.

Comment: Why doesn't an apple taste like an orange? Both are spheres and grow on trees.

Comment: @MrLister: In the context of a function declaration, this `int arr[]` is equivalent to `int * arr`.

Comment: @MrLister: The standard does. It states it is converted to a pointer. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7

Comment: You can't increment the pointer of an address. By doing `printf("%d\n", *arr + 1)` you can print the second element like you're trying to do, but that's it.

Comment: @Talaria: You probably meant `..., *(arr + 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

To quote `C11`, chapter 6.5.2.4, *Postfix increment and decrement operators*

> The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified real or pointer type, **and shall be a modifiable lvalue.**

and the definition of *modifiable lvalue* is given in chapter 6.3.2.1 of the same standard, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*

> **An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
>   designates an object;** [...] **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified
>   type.

So, you cannot use `++` on an array. Simple.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Array-Subscripts **bold** The array subscript expression A[i] is defined as being identical to the expression (*((A)+(i))). This means that many uses of an array name are equivalent to a pointer expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because C doesn't allow assigning to array. Arrays in expressions are automatically converted to a pointer pointing at the first element of the array unless they are used for the operand of `sizeof` operating or unary `&` (address) operator. (N1256 6.3.2.1)

As the error message shows, the operand `arr` is converted to a pointer pointing the first element of the array and the pointer isn't a lvalue, so it cannot be modified via increment operator.